# Xamarin.Forms: Thinking about ways to store images locally on the device user takes with camera

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In the proposed Xamarin app user is supposed to take multiple (5-30) images with camera and application is supposed to store them on the device to be available in the next session of user working with application. What would be the best way to do it? No needed for those images to be protected.

I think about 2 possible solutions: PCLStorage https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage, or binary data in sql-lite db https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/.

I'm new to Xamarin, so not sure pros and cons of each approach, and maybe there is another better option. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective, as I don't know PCLStorage that well, I would recommend that you can do one of the following.

1. Take photo normally with MediaPlugin. When it is stored on the device you get back path to it. You can store that path it in your database.
2. You can store blob of an image in the database.

If I were you I would simply create PoC with the first solution. Storing blobs in Db is time-consuming. With the first approach iOS/Android is taking care of the image being stored and you only take care of the link.

Comment: thank you for your recommendations. I'll try to go with option 1 first unless I hear something in favor of other approaches from other people. Just a small clarifying question: by "bolbs in Db is time-consuming" you meant time-consuming to make it implemented, not app performed, right? I guess first option performance must be better. Another question: are you sure with option 1 the path and file will stay there permanently with the app installed, even when application is removed from memory and new session is opened?

Comment: Actually I've meant both performance + implementation. The bigger the blob, the longer it takes to load it.
Yes, the image will be always there. The only problem is the user. If, for example, on Android, someone will clean app-data then bye-bye photos. You can back then up to the cloud but it's more of a business logic I guess

Comment: @YMC If you ever plan to share the pctures with other apps (i.e. display the image fullscreen with an already installed galery-app) storing to filesystem with proper file extensions is the way to go. Storing images in db will leave you with many unconventional problems.